# How to add a header to a table, and how to add a border in php

Tags: php, postgresql, formatting, multiple-columns

I have been writing queries to get information from a table in php. I can print out the information, but it does not look pretty at all. I was wondering how I could make the tables that are outputted better by having black lines as the borders of each cell, and also how to add a column header to my tables. Right now my output for my first query looks like this:

```
Massachusetts   152082
Missouri    151580
Illinois    111454
```

And I want my output to look like this (I also want each cell to have a black border):

```
district    population
Massachusetts   152082
Missouri    151580
Illinois    111454
```

Here is the code for when I print out my table. I dont think you will need any code from the queries so I wont post that. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
 echo "<table>\n";
                    while($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)){
                            echo "\t<tr>\n";
                            foreach($line as $col_value){
                                    echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
                            }

                    echo "\t</tr>\n";
            }
            echo "</table>\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
//table header
$table = "<table border='1px'>";
$table .= "<thead>";
$table .= "<tr>";
$i = pg_num_fields($result);
for ($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++) {
    $fieldname = pg_field_name($result, $j);
    $table .= "<th>$fieldname</th>"; 
}
$table .= "</tr>";
//table body
$table .= "<tbody>";  
while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $table .= "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $key => $value)
    {
        $table .= "<td>$value</td>";
    }
    $table .= "</tr>";  
}
$table .= "</tbody>";
$table .= "</table>";
//echo table
echo $table;
```

Comment: I switched this with the code that I have and now all it does it output the number 0

Comment: how would I go about writing a statement that tells the user how many rows are returned?

Comment: use `pg_num_rows($result);`

Comment: So like echo "The Query returned" . pg_num_rows($result)."lines";